# How do I use matplotlib's event handing inside wxPython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am attempting to modify the ["Draggable Rectangle Exercise"](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise) found in the matplotlib docs so that it works inside a wxPython window.

I have the following so far:

```
import wx

import matplotlib
matplotlib.interactive(True)
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

import numpy as np

class DraggableRectangle:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.press = None

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return

        contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
        if not contains: return
        print 'event contains', self.rect.xy
        x0, y0 = self.rect.xy
        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata

    def on_motion(self, event):
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if self.press is None: return
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        #print 'x0=%f, xpress=%f, event.xdata=%f, dx=%f, x0+dx=%f'%(x0, xpress, event.xdata, dx, x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

        #self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        self.press = None
        #self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

    def disconnect(self):
        'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(800,600))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, self.figure)

        rects = self.axes.bar(range(10), 20*np.random.rand(10))
        drs = []
        for rect in rects:
            dr = DraggableRectangle(rect)
            dr.connect()
            drs.append(dr)

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = Frame("test")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as advertised; the bars appear on the graph but they are not draggable at all.  Copying and pasting the example as-is works fine, it's only when I try to use it with wxPython that I run into problems.

Comment: Can you tell if your callbacks are firing or not?

Comment: I can tell with print statements -- they aren't.

Comment: Can you add the tool bar and see if the zoom and pan work correctly? I am trying to sort out if all callbacks are broken or just your new ones are not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but changing `drs` to `self.drs` (lines 75 and 79) seems to work. As if you had to prevent `drs`and all `dr` from being garbage collected. (Related to [Wx Matplotlib Event Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899231/wx-matplotlib-event-handling) ?)

```
import wx

import matplotlib
matplotlib.interactive(True)
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

import numpy as np

class DraggableRectangle:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.press = None

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        print "on_press"
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return

        contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
        if not contains: return
        print 'event contains', self.rect.xy
        x0, y0 = self.rect.xy
        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata

    def on_motion(self, event):
        print "on_motion"
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if self.press is None: return
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        #print 'x0=%f, xpress=%f, event.xdata=%f, dx=%f, x0+dx=%f'%(x0, xpress, event.xdata, dx, x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

        #self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

    def on_release(self, event):
        print "on_release"
        'on release we reset the press data'
        self.press = None
        #self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

    def disconnect(self):
        'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(800,600))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, self.figure)

        rects = self.axes.bar(range(10), 20*np.random.rand(10))
        self.drs = []
        for rect in rects:
            dr = DraggableRectangle(rect)
            dr.connect()
            self.drs.append(dr)

print "test"
app = wx.PySimpleApp()#redirect=False)
top = Frame("test")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```